# Is the instance_url of a sales force user remains same or is there a chance for a change to that?

Tags: salesforce

I am using salesforce login api to get the instance_url of a user. Is there any chance that the instance_url may change in later point of time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can change over time, your organization can be migrated to a new pod which would change the instance_url. The only long term stable URL is if you have my domains turned on and you use the my domains version of the url.